# Excel conditional formatting: directional arrows based on the value (like hand of a clock)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to use Conditional Formatting for the following purpose:

I need to display a directional arrows based on the value.

Ex.: 0 (arrow points to top); 180 (arrow point to bottom), 90 (arrow points to right), -90 (arrow points left). If the value is 15, arrow must reflect that change.

I am to have all kind of values from -180 to + 180.

Comment: How many arrow you want to have there, 4 or more? and what happens for values between the arrows, like if there is an arrow for 0 and one for 90 what should be the direction of 30?

Comment: is VBA-based solution acceptable? and: How many "arrows" is there likely to be in total?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I'd lke to have 18 positions, every 20 degrees.

Comment: Any solution is acceptable, thanks!

Comment: Gents, 12 positions are fine (every 30 deg)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is hard without VBA coding. I have done similar thing but using 8 different arrows (because I can find only 8 arrows from the Symbols menu). Here is how I did it. If someone knows how to add own icon sets with more arrows, this could be done easily using Condtional Formatting -feature in Excel.

To some cell, insert your sumbols found from Insert-ribbon:
[image]

So the content of a cell looks like shown below. You create a formula (shown in D1) that calculates which character to get from A1:

> =ROUND(C1/45;0)+4

(45 is a number 360 divided by 8)

[image]

Then yo draw an arrow:

> =RIGHT(LEFT($A$1;ABS(D1+1));1)

[image]

And you get the result something like this

[image]